# What formal representation is commonly used to describe compiler optimizations?

Tags: formal-languages, compilers, semantics, program-optimization, operational-semantics

I have devised a compiler optimization that works on any structured language that has arrays assignments `array[index] = value` and counted loops `(for i = n; i < N; i++) {doTHIS}` (*).

Now I want to represent this optimization using some formal semantics. Since I want to publish my results in a Programming Languages venue, I would like to know:

**What formal(s) representation(s) is (are) most commonly used to describe compiler optimizations?**

I have already described my optimization using operational semantics, but I'm currently reviewing this choice. Hence, I came to the community for advice.

(*) Please forgive this C-like representation in a question asking for formal semantics.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many compilers, which compile widely different kinds of languages which serve widely different purposes. For example, a database language will have very different optimizations than an array-based language like APL.

Compilers themselves use several intermediate languages, from the input language, to a de-sugared version of the input language, all the way down to "fancy" assembly-like versions. You might check [here](http://compcert.inria.fr/compcert-C.html#archi) to get an idea of the intermediate languages involved.

Optimizations happen at each of these stages. In general it only makes sense to state optimizations in terms of a formal execution semantics of the language in question: an optimization must preserve the *observational semantics*, aka the result of the computation. Ideally you would use the semantics to say something about the *execution time* as well: typically the number of abstract reduction steps would get lower (in certain cases) after application of the optimization.

Pragmatically, many optimizations of imperative-style languages happen on an intermediate language that looks a lot like [LLVM IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM#Intermediate_representation). Characteristics include [SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) (no variable repeated in the left-hand-side of an assignment) and [three address code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code) (at most one assignment, and one operation per statement).

The function calls, thunks, memory layout and semantics of things like pointers are going to tend to be specific to your language.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  If I understand correctly, optimizations are expressed using the execution semantics of a given language, which in turn can be written as: a) Natural language b) another type of formal semantics (such as operational semantics)?

Comment: @ElMarce that is correct. A large part of field of computer science could perhaps be summarized as "ways to describe program meanings" often with the view of doing exactly what you are doing, i.e. proving the correctness of a program transformation.